# Why does my Acer Aspire 4730Z cursor jump randomly when typing?

Tags: keyboard, cursor

When typing a sentence, the cursor jumps randomly from one spot to another. I can't complete a sentence without going back and retyping it.

I was told it may be the touch pad sensitivity, but its not. I already tried disabling it and it still did the same thing.

I get the sense that the computer casing and/or keyboard area is flexing, causing the problem when I type but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a wireless mouse/keyboard make sure their batteries aren't running low (low batteries in these devices can cause this type of unreliability).

For the track pad (which laptops use as a mouse), try disabling the "tap to click" feature in the mouse driver (should be in Control Panel somewhere if it's not in your System Tray), as clicks can be detected unintentionally when we drag our palms over it.

I find that disabling the "tap to click" feature resolves all sorts of unintentional mouse actions including drag-and-drop when using laptops because I like to rest my palms on the chassis when typing.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of Windows doing that on it's own; I have, however, written programs to do that ;)
Anyways, now for the answer:
Could you be hitting the touch pad while you're typing? If your arms/hands are hitting the touch pad while you are typing, that would cause the erratic movements you are describing.

If you are sure that this is not happening, then have you run any programs from anybody who would have an interest in practical joking lately? ;)
(jk) [actually I'm half serious; I did this to one of my friends once :) ]